# Sepolia Testnet

Tags: testnets, database, sepolia

I am using Sepolia testnet to work and develop my dapp. I created the contract and deployed to the Sepolia network. I will be making several transactions in this similar manner. I know it is possible to check individual transaction using tx hash. But, is it possible to **access the entire file where blockchain and its transactions is stored**? I want to analyze the transactions I have made. If it is not possible here? Is there any other test networks I can use to develop my dapp  that will allow me to download the entire blockchain. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Sepolia Testnet also works in the same manner compare to other blockchain. If you search on the 'etherscan.io' with your transaction address, then you can find your contract by each transaction. Is this an answer that you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not fully grasp how a Blockchain works.

A Blockchain is a **chain of blocks**, stored in a decentralized manner in thousands of nodes and therefore there isn't a file where **blockchain and its transactions are stored**, but thousand of copies of a Blockchain, block by block. I think the Ethereum Blockchain for instance weighs 720Giga as of today.

A Blockchain is a ledger. Etherscan is basically an API that accesses the Ethereum Blockchain and searches a particular tx in all the blocks of a Blockchain.

**There is no such thing as a Blockchain file**.

In general as a *good practice for developing a Dapp* developers will **first deploy on local testnet** for speed, accessibility and readability.

There are **3 main Smart Contract** development frameworks that come with their own test network:

- [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/)
- [Truffle suite](https://trufflesuite.com/)
- [Foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry)

They all have their own set of tools, advantages and disadvantages.

However to a beginner smart contract dev i would personally recommend the use of [Ganache](https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/) from the Truffle suite. It comes with a GUI that is for a starter a great way to get the hands on it, vizualize and grasp the key concepts and inner workings of transactions, a blockchain ...

[image]

***Disclaimer: the next sentences only reflect my own opinion.***

I personally would see *Truffle* as the perfect entry point for a beginner Smart Contract developer, to then moving on to *Hardhat* that is more complex but has more tools or extensions and is faster, to finally end with *Foundry* which is the most complex but , in my opinion,the fastest, the most complete and powerful for Smart Contracts development.

Answer (score 0):

To download and explore the entire blockchain history you have to run Full Archive Node of preferred network.